# GCC mtune performance

Tags: optimization, gcc, apt

Can I change the gcc binary on my ubuntu installation to a program that calls gcc with the parameters -march=native -mtune=core2 -Os -O2, so that every time I install a program or lib with apt it will be properly optimized? Will I have any problems when installing they?

Comment: `apt` does not build and install packages from source, instead it just pulls in prebuilt binaries for the package from the repository.

Comment: What if i use apt-build?

Comment: You can run `dpkg-reconfigure apt-build` and choose the optimization flags you'd like to be used for all packages built using `apt-build`. The settings would be written into `/etc/apt/apt-build.conf `. Look at this: http://www.togaware.com/linux/survivor/Build_Architecture.html page for more info.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? In practice, the performance gain will be small (Debian packages are very often already compiled with `-O2`) -probably less than 1%-, and every installation would compile the source code, which may take ages....

Comment: -Os -O2 doesn't make sense. -march=native -mtune=core2 doesn't either. And you run the risk of hitting more compiler/program bugs, instead of relying on the same binary packages that are used by many other people. Besides, for some packages where it makes a difference, there are already several binaries provided by the distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Gentoo Linux](http://www.gentoo.org/). It's a Linux distro based exactly on the concept that you can configure your compiler flags, and all the packages are compiled locally to those settings.